# Why am I unable to delete objects (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, javascript-objects

I've got the below code and I can't seem to find a way to remove the mainThumbs from the thumbs object. I've tried with splice(0,(mainThumbs.length - 1)), shift, delete thumbs[0] and nothing seems to work. The functions render the following error 'Uncaught TypeError: thumbs.shift() is not a function' while the delete thumbs[0] just returns the thumbs whole and untouched.

```
var thumbs      = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');
var mainThumbs  = document.querySelectorAll('.main-thumbnail');

for(var i = 0; i < mainThumbs.length; i++){
    delete thumbs[0];

    console.log(thumbs);
}
```

This is how mainThumbs looks like:

```
(3) [div.thumbnail.main-thumbnail, div.thumbnail.main-thumbnail, div.thumbnail.main-thumbnail]
```

This is what the console outputs for thumbs:

```
(12) [div.thumbnail.main-thumbnail, div.thumbnail.main-thumbnail, div.thumbnail.main-thumbnail, div.thumbnail.modal-open, div.thumbnail, div.thumbnail, div.thumbnail, div.thumbnail, div.thumbnail, div.thumbnail, div.thumbnail, div.thumbnail]
```

and the typeOf thumbs and mainThumbs is object

Can anyone explain why I can't seem to be able to remove the mainThumbs from the thumbs object? 
I would also like a solution with splice rather than delete or shift as I find it to be more accurate.

Comment: are you trying to remove them from the array or the dom?

Comment: @JohnRodney — What array? There is no array.

Comment: Both then above console outputs are array notation.  Arraylike objects that are returned by the `querySelectorAll` function.  They can be turned into an array using `[].slice.apply(res)`.  Then use `element.parentNode.removeChild(element);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` does not return an array. In some ways the object is array-like, but not in all.

Your approach to this problem is over-complicated though. Instead of getting all the elements that are `.thumbnail` and then trying to remove the ones which are `.main-thumbnail`, just make one search using [the negation pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

```
var non_main_thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail:not(.main-thumbnail)');
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the possibility of negating in a search. THANKS A LOT MAN!

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll('.thumbnail')`

1. Returns collection not array.
2. But you can borrow slice method from Array object and create your own real array:

> ```
> var thumbs      = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');
> var mainThumbs  = document.querySelectorAll('.main-thumbnail');
>
> var thumbsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(thumbs);
> var mainThumbsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(mainThumbs);
>
> for(var i = 0; i < mainThumbsArr.length; i++){
>     delete thumbsArr[0];
>     console.log(thumbsArr);
> }
> ```